# Data not binding to listbox in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, listbox

I have listbox

```
 @Html.ListBox("lais", new SelectList(Model.lista, "Value", "Text"), new {@class = "mylistbox"});
```

Here am getting list data but not binding to listbox (list items value )

This is my action method

```
 public ActionResult PrintRFIDTag()
    {
        Print p =new Print();
        p.lista = GetList();

        return View(p);

    }

    public SelectList GetList()
    {
        System.Management.ManagementScope objMS =
            new System.Management.ManagementScope(ManagementPath.DefaultPath);
        objMS.Connect();
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        SelectQuery objQuery = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer");
        ManagementObjectSearcher objMOS = new ManagementObjectSearcher(objMS, objQuery);
        System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMOS.Get();
        foreach (ManagementObject Printers in objMOC)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(Printers["Network"]))     // ALL NETWORK PRINTERS.
            {
                var emptyItem = new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Value = Printers["Name"].ToString(),
                    Text = "00"
                };

                items.Add(emptyItem);

            }
        }
        SelectList objselectlist = new SelectList(items,"Value");
        return objselectlist;
    }

}
```

Here is my model class

```
  public class Print
{
    public SelectList lista { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Returning from view but not binding to listbox
Your help will be appropriated

Comment: What is the `Model` you pass on your `View`?

Comment: Plz check the latest edited code

Comment: in Model.lista am getting data in view but not binding

Comment: just try this `@Html.ListBox("lais", Model.lista, new {@class = "mylistbox"});`

Comment: not getting .am getting system.web.mvc.selectlistitem in listbox

Comment: what if you change this line `SelectList objselectlist = new SelectList(items,"Value");` to this: `SelectList objselectlist = new SelectList(items,"Value","Text")`;

Comment: Even if changed as per above comment same am getting system.web.mvc.selectlistitem in listbox

Comment: I hope this one will help `@Html.ListBoxFor(m=>m.lista ,Model.lista, new {@class = "mylistbox"})` with the last comment

Comment: In Model.lista when i click on + model.lista + base +items values am getting my value AM getting same thing through @Html.ListBoxFor(m=>m.lista ,Model.lista)

Comment: I don't get you. have a look here to construct your SelectList:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: In view Model.lista on mouse over i expanded + model.lista under this +base +items [0] value here my value got but not binding to m=>m.lista

Comment: It is correct. m=>m.lista is to provide the `Expression`

Comment: @Html.ListBoxFor(m=>m.lista ,Model.lista) this is the expression

Comment: `ListBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(HtmlHelper<TModel>, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, Object)`

Comment: When you try this:`@Html.ListBoxFor(m=>m.lista ,Model.lista)`. have you the result?

Comment: ya i got the result but not binding to listbox

Comment: try this:@Html.ListBoxFor(m=>m.lista ,Model.lista) and change line `SelectList objselectlist = new SelectList(items,"Value")`; to this: `SelectList objselectlist = new SelectList(items,"Value","Text")`

Comment: Thanq so much i got with the above .@ lnanikian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:
`@Html.ListBoxFor(m=>m.lista ,Model.lista)` and change line `SelectList objselectlist = new SelectList(items,"Value");` to this: `SelectList objselectlist = new SelectList(items,"Value","Text");`